# How to pass enum value in param for request with typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, angular9

I use ng-swagger-gen to generate classes, methods, etc... using swagger generated by my back end.

for this request:

```
  consoleUsercashOutUsingPOST(consoleUserTransactionDto: ConsoleUserTransactionDto): __Observable<ConsoleUserTransaction> {
    return this.consoleUsercashOutUsingPOSTResponse(consoleUserTransactionDto).pipe(
      __map(_r => _r.body as ConsoleUserTransaction)
    );
  }
```

swagger-gen generated this interface param:

/* tslint:disable */

```
export interface ConsoleUserTransactionDto {
  action?: 'COMPANY_ACTIVATION' | 'IN_APP_PURCHASE' | 'APP_PURCHASE' | 'MUSIC_PURCHASE' | 'EBOOK_PURCHASE' | 'USER_DOWNLOAD_APP';
  amount?: number;
  companyUuid?: number;
  consoleUserUuid?: string;
  isCashIn?: boolean;
  mobileMoneyServiceCode?: string;
  phoneNumber?: string;}
```

To call the method, i use it like this:

```
 // Initialise cash out transaction
    const consoleUserTransactionDto = {phoneNumber: this.cashOutPhoneNumberModel, consoleUserUuid: consoleUserId,
      companyUuid: companyUid, amount: amountToPay,
      mobileMoneyServiceCode: mobileMoney, isCashIn: false, action: CompanyAction.COMPANY_ACTIVATION};

    // Start cash out
    await this.consoleUserTransactionService.consoleUsercashOutUsingPOST(consoleUserTransactionDto).toPromise().then({ 

})
```

But I got the error

```
 Argument of type '{ phoneNumber: string; consoleUserUuid: string; companyUuid: number; amount: number; mobileMoneyServiceCode: any; i
sCashIn: boolean; action: CompanyAction; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConsoleUserTransactionDto'.
  Types of property 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'CompanyAction' is not assignable to type '"COMPANY_ACTIVATION" | "IN_APP_PURCHASE" | "APP_PURCHASE" | "MUSIC_PURCHASE" | "EBOOK_PURCHASE" | "USER_DOWNLOAD_APP"'.

188     await this.consoleUserTransactionService.consoleUsercashOutUsingPOST(consoleUserTransactionDto).toPromise().then(company => {
```

because i set action with a string `action: CompanyAction.COMPANY_ACTIVATION` instead of `'"COMPANY_ACTIVATION" | "IN_APP_PURCHASE" | "APP_PURCHASE" | "MUSIC_PURCHASE" | "EBOOK_PURCHASE" | "USER_DOWNLOAD_APP"'`

How could I do to pass the correct enum type ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create enum and assign to model as type of action property

example create file action-response.enum

```
export enum ActionResponseEnum{
   COMPANY_ACTIVATION= 'COMPANY_ACTIVATION',
   IN_APP_PURCHASE= 'IN_APP_PURCHASE',
     .......
}
```

then in the property

```
action?: ActionResponseEnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

So `action?: 'COMPANY_ACTIVATION' | 'IN_APP_PURCHASE' | 'APP_PURCHASE' | 'MUSIC_PURCHASE' | 'EBOOK_PURCHASE' | 'USER_DOWNLOAD_APP';` are types. As if I have `action?: 'string' | 'int' ;`

So to use it just creat a variable with the type you want

```
 let action : 'COMPANY_ACTIVATION' = 'COMPANY_ACTIVATION';
```

and use it

```
const consoleUserTransactionDto = {phoneNumber: this.cashOutPhoneNumberModel, consoleUserUuid: consoleUserId,
  companyUuid: companyUid, amount: amountToPay,
  mobileMoneyServiceCode: mobileMoney, isCashIn: false, action: action };
```